# Getting count of repeating column data along side with the data it self

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a SQLite database, and I have a column named issue_id I am trying to get all the issue_id and merge them so it returns unique issue_id aslong side with how many repeating issue_id there are

[image]

This is an image of the data my database holds.

I'm trying to get an Array from this data the array would include:

all the columns and the count of matching issue_id.]

So 2 arrays with the following:

```
issue_id                           issue_id_count
38b6bb13b5aef92df2f5385e1952e7ff   3
555ec146b11c53fc3ea1ce0c139b915a   1
```

What I have tried so far is

```
SELECT
  issue_id,
  count(issue_id) as issue_id_count,
FROM
  crashes
WHERE
  issue_id = ?
```

and using PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT FROM crashes WHERE issue_id = ? count(issue_id) as issue_id_count";
$res = $database->getConnection()->query($sql);
while ($tab = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
// handle data here
}
```

The SQL not not valid, Since I have limited knowledge towards SQL thats what I was able to come up with, Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong or how I can achieve what I want to do?

Edit so far I have this:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(issue_id) as issue_id_count FROM crashes WHERE issue_id = ? ";

$res = $database->getConnection()->query($sql);

if (!$res) die(mysqli_error($database->getConnection()));

while ($tab = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $var = $tab['issue_id_count'];
}
```

but I am getting error on `?` of SQL.

Comment: You can't use `COUNT()` after a `WHERE` clause here. That's why your php method is failing. You also didn't select anything.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a `GROUP BY` clause if you wish to use the `count` aggregate function that way:

```
SELECT
  issue_id,
  count(issue_id) as issue_id_count
FROM
  crashes
GROUP BY
  issue_id
```

Comment: I'm sure they'll probably like an explanation as to why you posted this and why their code didn't work for them as they'd like it to. Edit: ok, right on. This as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53678087/1

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I guess it's my competitive nature that makes me post the meat of the answer first and then the reasoning in successive edits.

Comment: LOL!! I see :-)

Comment: Are you not require to tell SQL you want to group to `issue_id_count`?

Comment: @SamzSakerz no, because that value is the *result* of the grouping

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM crashes GROUP BY issue_id' at line 4

Comment: That's what I get when I run the query.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner did you delete your answer out of frustration?

Comment: @JonathanWilson *lo!!* no, not out of frustration, just unclear at the point where they asked something that wasn't part of the original question. I might go back to it later with a fresher head, since I'm kind of max'ed out for tonight. Head's gone to mush.

Comment: Sorry If it wasn't clear but the title always has been `count of repeating column` and I explained in the post what output I want to do, English is not my first language :D

Comment: Sorry, forgot all about it. I'll take another look soon. I emailed myself a reminder ;)